# How can I create a JSON object dynamically?

Tags: php, json

I would like to create a JSON object dynamically. The JSON object will have to be as the follows:

```
{ 
                $capa:[$fila['test_name'],...etc],
                .
                .
                .etc    

};
```

The key and value will be retrieved through a MySQL query.
This is what i'm doing:

```
$array_container= array();

while($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){


                    $format_org=str_replace(" ","_",$fila["organization"]);
                    $format_eval=str_replace(" ","_",$fila["EvaluationType"]);
                    $format_test=str_replace(" ","_",$fila["test_name"]);
                                        $CapaEnviar=$format_org.$format_eval;

                              $array_container[] = array($CapaEnviar => $fila['test_name']);

}

echo json_encode($array_container,true);
```

Using the previous code, I can retrieve a JSON object with duplicate keys.

This code is an answer for an AJAX request, so once the JSON object has been created correctly, I will send back this JSON object in order to retrieve the key and value, so I will have to retrieve separately the key and value.

Comment: You already are creating a JSON object dynamically when issuing json_encode($array_container,true), so I'm not sure what you're asking for. Please clarify, and show what you've tried so far.

Comment: what i'm trying is create a an dynamic array  and then convert it to  json object. the results of this array is as the follows:
` [{"TEST1":"valueT1"},{"TEST1":"otherValue"}] `

and what i'm looking for is to have a json like this:

` [{"TEST1":['valueT1','otherValue']}]  `

as you can see, i want to avoid duplicates keys. if is possible to check if there are an existing key .

Comment: Ha, I see, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Note: This line `$array_container[] = array($CapaEnviar => $fila['test_name']);` should be `$array_container[] = array($CapaEnviar => $format_test);`, don't you think?

Comment: no, fila['test_name'] is correct, because i want that user show  text  whitout  "_"

Comment: @riztak Ok, I've also updated my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment,

> ...the results of this array is as the follows: `[{"TEST1":"valueT1"},{"TEST1":"otherValue"}]` and what i'm looking for is to have a json like this: `[{"TEST1":['valueT1','otherValue']}]` as you can see, i want to avoid duplicates keys.

**Solution:**

In your `while` loop, change this line

```
$array_container[] = array($CapaEnviar => $fila['test_name']);
```

to

```
$array_container[$CapaEnviar][] = $fila['test_name'];
```

**Update:**

> how i can retrieve this key and their values through ajax?

Since you're expecting a json object from server, add this setting `dataType:'json'` to your AJAX request. `dataType` is the type of data you're expecting back from the server. And in the `success()` callback function, loop through the json result to get (key, value) pairs

Here's the reference:

- [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

So your AJAX skeleton code should be like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'yourpage.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: 'false',

    beforeSend: function(){

    },

    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            alert("Key:" + key + ", value: " + value);
        });
    },

    error: function(){
        // error
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, is working good!.

By the way , how i can retrieve this key and their values through ajax?

Comment: i want to retrieve the name of key and their values, somebody has an idea?

Comment: Are you using an ajax library, something like jQuery?

Comment: @riztak I've updated my answer. Please see the **Update** section of my answer.